# If two clauses are connected by "and", do they necessarily have the same tenses?

Tags: tenses

If two sentences are connected by "and", do they necessarily have the same tenses? For example, is the following sentence correct?

"I enjoyed the trip, and I like the food"

Comment: Those are separate sentences. Separate sentences never have to agree with each other in any way to be grammatical—only context decides what is proper in any given case. Example: “My father was a plumber, and I am a plumber, and my son will be a plumber, too.” Putting all those in the same tense would drastically change the meaning, but not the grammaticality.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas linked by *and* can easily cross the lines between past, present, and future, as Janus Bahs Jacquet demonstrates in his excellent example in the comments beneath the poster's question. However, *and* does impose some logical constraints on what you can reasonably pair with what without disorienting your readers or listeners slightly.

In the example, "I enjoyed the trip, and I like the food," we don't have enough information to form a complete and accurate idea of what (if any) connection the speaker is making between the trip and the food. For instance, the statement may be a complete response to a friend's double question:

> How was your trip? And what do you think of the meal I've just served you?

In this case, the statement merely answers the questions asked, accurately and in the proper tenses. Alternatively the speaker's statement may (incompletely) express this more detailed idea:

> I enjoyed the trip [to India], and I like the food [of India]."

In this case, too, the transition from past tense (to express an opinion about the trip) to present tense (to express an opinion about the food that people in India eat) doesn't pose any problems of coherence. Or again, the speaker may have intended to say this:

> I enjoyed the trip [to India], and I like the food [I ate there].

In this case, the transition from past tense (to express an opinion about the trip) to present tense (to express an opinion about the food that the traveler ate during the trip) seems not quite right. I may like palak paneer as a hypothetical dinner option in the present, but my relationship to the particular palak paneer that I ate last weekend in Lucknow is in the past—and my insisting that I continue to like that specific, now-consumed pint of pureed spinach and cheese chunks five days later (postdigestion, as it were) may make hearers wonder at my ardency.

It is far more common to express those linked ideas in the same time frame. And the same goes for a linked comment about a person's trip to wherever and the food the person ate while visiting there:

> I enjoyed the trip [to India], and I liked the food [I ate there].